# Ruby on Rails 5 complex scope query with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models Product, Option and Comment. A product has many options, and has many comments. An option belongs to product and a comment belongs to product.

I’d like to create a scope inside the Comment model to get all the comments where the product_id matches the product_id inside the Option model, then checks if the attribute “message” inside the Comment model is LIKE any of the options belonging to that product_id. I have a worker which passes the product variable into the Comments model.

I can get close using the following code, but I’d like to make it dynamic instead of hardcoding the second part of the query.

**Comments.rb**

```
scope :get_options, -> (product) { where(“comments.product_id = ? AND comments.message LIKE ?”), product.id, “Large Blue” }
```

Here, `Large Blue` is an example of an option existing in the Option table.

This scope is emulating what i am trying to return, but I’d like to call the Options belonging to that product instead of hardcoding it.

Any help with best practices on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you can take it from product.options by association inside the scope which return all the options related to product ... now the game is yours

Comment: I left you an answer. Can you please also paste here `Product`, `Option` and `Comment` fields and associations?

Comment: Are you saying you would like to be able to pass a specific option, or one of its attributes, into the scope, and see if there are comments for that product with that one option? or are you looking to see if any of the comments associated with a product have messages like ANY of the options associated with that product?

Comment: I am trying to see if any of the comments associated with a product have messages like any of the options associated with that product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sqlite

```
Comment.joins(product: :options).where("comments.product_id = ? AND comments.message LIKE '%' || options.title || '%'")
```

I think this should be pretty close to work you look

Comment: Thanks! This got me close. Sometimes the comments.message has more content than just the options.title value. I was wondering if its possible to check if the options.title exists inside of the comments.message?

I've tried this
Comment.joins(product: :options).where("comments.product_id = ? AND comments.message LIKE '%' + 'options.title' + '%'") but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What database server do you use? MySQL? (updated my answer for MySQL)

Comment: Currently using sqlite3

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it and answer whether it works for you

Comment: This worked! Using || instead of + for concatenation.
Comment.joins(product: :options).where("comments.product_id = ? AND comments.message LIKE '%' || options.title || '%'")

Comment: Updated my answer with your final solution. It would be ready great if you mark it as answer for your question for future search